# MYSQL reading a file from internal network and external network Why Packets out of order?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

why can i read a table translated by php on a mysql server from inside the network but get "packets out of order" outside the network with the same type of browser?  Is it just that MYSQL does something different when transmitting data across the internet?  Using xampp with ip forwarded to 3306

Comment: You can't get "packets out of order" over TCP. Do you mean the *table* is displayed in a different order?

Comment: no, php displays the table just fine when I am within the local network, as soon as I go to my remote computer it gets "J 5.5.39sakw5@#.ÿ÷€YX/!Tg)4g.Lsmysql_native_password!ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order"

Comment: I suggest you post the PHP code and the *exact* error message, in your question.

Comment: I've tried several different files: raw xml, .php files outputting xml, .php outputting JSON.  All work on perfectly in my LAN, as soon as I go outside the lan and connect through the internet I get packets out of order or the webpage tries to download the file instead.  Don't think it's the code but more likely a setting in xampp or MYSQL.

Comment: So it isn't a programming question, so it's off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out, my main IP was forwarding to x.x.x.x:3306 instead it should have been forwarded to :80.  As soon as it was opened I was able to download everything I wanted.

Comment: 3306 is the default port for MySQL. 80 is the default port for HTTP. If you confuse them it's impossible to get a mostly working application with only "packets out of order" (whatever that means).